# Why my code is throwing NullPointerException though it's fine with logic and also passes the sample testcases?

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

The code is on gfg : https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/swap-kth-node-from-beginning-and-kth-node-from-end-in-a-singly-linked-list/1

Our task is to complete the function swapkthnode()

What's wrong with this particular code? It works fine for custom checking of sample testcases/example given in the problem itself. I have tested sample cases in online IDE jdoodle, it's working fine there.
But on compile & test in gfg IDE, It is giving NullPointerException(segmentation fault in c++ for same logic) on line commented below;

```
Node swapkthnode(Node head, int num, int K)
{
    // your code here
    if(num == 1 || 2*K - 1 == num) return head;
    if(K == 1 || K == num)
    {
        Node start = head;
        Node end = head;
        
        while(end.next.next != null) end = end.next;
        
        head = end.next;
        head.next = start.next;
        end.next = start;
        start.next = null;
        return head;
    }
    else
    {
        Node lastK = head;
        Node firstK = head;
        
        for(int i=K-2; i>0; i--) firstK = firstK.next;
        for(int i=num-K-1; i>0; i--) lastK = lastK.next;
        
        Node tmp1 = firstK.next;
        Node tmp2 = lastK.next.next;

        firstK.next = lastK.next;
        lastK.next = tmp1;
        firstK.next.next = tmp1.next; // <<<===== May be This is the faulty line according to exception thrown, but I am unable to see any fault in there.
        tmp1.next = tmp2; // beacause if firstK.next is going to be null in any example,
        return head; // then it will be already handled by above 2nd if condition.
    }
}
```

StackTrace : [stackTrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhXpi.png)

Comment: If you suspect that line, why didn't you check `firstK.next` for null?  Can you provide the stacktrace indicating specific line of code?

Comment: @AlexRudenko Look at the stackTrace, I have uploaded it. swapkthnode is inside class "GFG". For further code (Driver code - apart from this function) which is provided by problem designer, you can visit the link I have given, but I think driver code has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Could not reproduce this issue with your _available_ code.  Possibly the issue is related to incorrect build of the linked list.  I suggest that you catch the NPE and print the contents of the linked list to identify the reason.

Comment: I guess you are right, closing the question! @AlexRudenko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not reproduce the issue with your code for the following tests:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] tests = {
                {1,2, 3, 4},
                {1,2, 3, 4, 5},
                {1,2, 3, 4},
                {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                {1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8},
        };

        int[] testK = {1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 2};

        for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
            Node head = buildNode(tests[i]);
            System.out.println("\nBefore swap at position " + testK[i] + ": " + dumpNode(head));

            Node result = swapkthnode(head, tests[i].length, testK[i]);

            System.out.println("After swap: " + dumpNode(result));
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Before swap at position 1: 1=>2=>3=>4
After swap: 4=>2=>3=>1

Before swap at position 3: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5
After swap: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5

Before swap at position 4: 1=>2=>3=>4
After swap: 4=>2=>3=>1

Before swap at position 3: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9
After swap: 1=>2=>7=>4=>5=>6=>3=>8=>9

Before swap at position 2: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8=>9
After swap: 1=>8=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>2=>9

Before swap at position 3: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8
After swap: 1=>2=>6=>4=>5=>3=>7=>8

Before swap at position 2: 1=>2=>3=>4=>5=>6=>7=>8
After swap: 1=>7=>3=>4=>5=>6=>2=>8
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility of `end.next` being `null`. This could lead NPE at  `while(end.next.next != null) end = end.next;`

Try to fix this by doing `end.next != null && end.next.next != null` if this satisfies your logic.

Comment: I guess you didn't get my question or the logic of the code completely.
I have write first condition to check two things:
1) If the list has only one Node
2) If the node to be swapped is the middle node.

hence if the 2nd "if" condition : `if(K == 1 || K == num)` is going to be executed, then the list will have certainly at least two nodes and hence `end.next` is never going to be `null`.

and this exception is due to something somewhere in the rest of the code I guess.